# Congruences divisibility and the primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Suppose that $p_1,p_2,...,p_r$ are the only primes congruent to $1\ (\text{mod}\ 4)$. Prove that $4p_1^2p_2^2...p_r^2+1$ is divisible only by the primes congruent to $3\ (\text{mod}\ 4)$. So far all I have been able to do is prove there are infinitely many primes congruent to $3\ (\text{mod}\ 4)$

Comment: $$(4p_1^2p_2^2...p_r^2+1,p_r)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Are you assuming that there are only finitely many primes $\equiv1\pmod4$
for sake of contradiction?

If $p$ is a prime factor of $4m^2+1$ with $m$ an integer, then $p$ is
odd, and $(2m)^2\equiv-1\pmod p$, that is $-1$ is a quadratic residue
modulo $p$. Do you know a criterion for when $-1$ is a quadratic residue?